# Playing Multiple sounds at the same time in Android

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am unable to use the following code to play multiple sounds/beeps simultaneously. In my `onclicklistener` I have added:

```java
public void onClick(View v) { 
    mSoundManager.playSound(1); 
    mSoundManager.playSound(2); 
}
```

But this plays only one sound at a time, sound with index 1 followed by sound with index 2.

How can I play at least 2 sounds simultaneously using this code whenever there is an `onClick()` event?

```java
public class SoundManager {

    private  SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private  AudioManager  mAudioManager;
    private  Context mContext;

    public SoundManager() {
        
    }
        
    public void initSounds(Context theContext) { 
        mContext = theContext;
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); 
        mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);          
    }

    public void addSound(int Index,int SoundID) {
        mSoundPoolMap.put(1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));
    }

    public void playSound(int index) { 
        int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
    }

    public void playLoopedSound(int index) {
        int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, -1, 1f); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you're storing each sound with the same index in your `mSoundPoolMap` ... `mSoundPoolMap.put(1, ...`

Comment: Hi Roman,

When I have to use the above code, I change the mSoundPoolMap method to  mSoundPoolMap.put(index, mSoundPool.load(mContext, SoundID, 1));

And when I have use and play the sounds I do this-
             final SoundManager  mSoundManager = new SoundManager();                     
  mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
  mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.1);
     mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.2);
     mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.2);          
So that means the index 1,2 and 3 go to mSoundPoolMap.put(). But even then I am unable to play the sounds simultaneously. Pleas help.

Answer (score 7):

Having the following class to play sound fx using sound pool:

```
public class SoundManager {

    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_MENU_BTN         = 0;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_WIN              = 1;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_LOOSE            = 2;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_DRAW             = 3;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK1            = 4;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK2            = 5;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_OUT_OF_TIME      = 6;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_HISCORE          = 7;
    public static int SOUNDPOOLSND_CORRECT_LETTER   = 8;

    public static boolean isSoundTurnedOff;

    private static SoundManager mSoundManager;

    private SoundPool mSoundPool; 
    private SparseArray <Integer> mSoundPoolMap; 
    private AudioManager  mAudioManager;

    public static final int maxSounds = 4;

    public static SoundManager getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (mSoundManager == null){
            mSoundManager = new SoundManager(context);
        }

        return mSoundManager;
   }

    public SoundManager(Context mContext)
    {
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(maxSounds, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

//        mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
//            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
//               loaded = true;
//            }
//        });

        mSoundPoolMap = new SparseArray<Integer>(); 
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_MENU_BTN, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.menubutton, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_WIN, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.win, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_LOOSE, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.lose, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK1, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.tick_0, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_TICK2, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.tick_1, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_OUT_OF_TIME, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.out_of_time, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_HISCORE, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.personal_highscore, 1));
        mSoundPoolMap.put(SOUNDPOOLSND_CORRECT_LETTER, mSoundPool.load(mContext, R.raw.correct_letter, 1));

        // testing simultaneous playing
        int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(0), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 20, 1f); 
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(1), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 2, 1f);
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(2), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f);


    } 

    public void playSound(int index) { 
        if (isSoundTurnedOff)
            return;

         int streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
         mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(index), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1f); 
    }

    public static void clear()
    {
        if (mSoundManager != null){
            mSoundManager.mSoundPool = null; 
            mSoundManager.mAudioManager = null;
            mSoundManager.mSoundPoolMap = null;
        }
        mSoundManager = null;
    }
}
```

it DOES play simultaneously 3 sounds mentioned below the comment "testing simultaneous playing". It seems like you need to implement commented in my code listener (`OnLoadCompleteListener`). It could happen that system just didn't load sounds atm you start playing it. If you dont want to implement mentioned listener try to wait some time after your playing sounds activity started and start playing sounds after a while.

Comment: Please, note that SoundPool cannot be used for sounds longer than several seconds or audio files >1MB.