# Why are my SoundPool sounds not playing simultaneously in onClick()?

Tags: android, soundpool

When I click, the following code leads the two sounds to be played not simultaneously, but sequentially.  Why are they not played simultaneously?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mytextview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    mytextview.setOnClickListener(this);

    sp=(SoundPool) new SoundPool(8,0x00000003,1);
    upSound=sp.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
    downSound=sp.load(this, R.raw.sound2, 1);
}

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sp.play(downSound, VOLUME, VOLUME, 1, 0, 1);
    sp.play(upSound, VOLUME, VOLUME, 1, 0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to play sound like on down and on up user action ?

Comment: Try playing the second file using mediaplayer. then it will play simultaneously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one very important piece of information that I don't see a lot when working with sound files:
**DO NOT USE WAV**'s !!!

you'll see weird behavior, which can vary from phone to phone.

**ALWAYS USE OGG** !!!

Comment: rly helped me ! thx a lot ! with .wav its actually was behaving weird. Sometimes it was playing , sometimes no sound at all. After converting it to ogg using some online converters, its working ^^ thx

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627101/playing-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-android). In an answer to that question, there is a link to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039078/android-playing-multiple-sounds-using-soundmanager/3763993#3763993) to yet another question that may be of some help, in case you are still looking...