# Play next sound without waiting for previous playback to end

Tags: java, android

I am making a roulette game type application, I have 10 rectangles that change color simulating a random choice, In addition to the color change, I want a sound to be played every time the roulette goes through a rectangle.

First a list of possible prizes is created `awardList`, then the winner is randomly selected `positionAwardSelected`

I tried to do the following:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
int count = 0;

private void playRoulette(){
    List<Award> awardList = new ArrayList<>();
    int  positionAwardSelected;
    // ... List filling and winner selection code (not necessary to include for the question) ...
    int numberMovements = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(20, 60 + 1);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pin);
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count > numberMovements){
                resetColors();
                getConstrainLayoutRectangle(positionAwardSelected).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Roulette.this, R.drawable.selected_rectangle));
            } else {
                resetColors();
                int randomPosition = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, awardList.size());
                getConstrainLayoutRectangle(randomPosition).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(Roulette.this, R.drawable.selected_rectangle));
            }
            mp.start();
            if (count++ < numberMovements) {//Time it takes to change the rectangle, before the winner 70% of the time it takes 175ms and 30% of the time it takes 250ms, to change to the winner it takes 100ms
                handler.postDelayed(this, timeDelay());
            } else {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
}

private int timeDelay(){
    int a = new Random().nextInt(100);
    if (a >= 30){
        return 175;
    } else {
        return 250;
    }
}
```

Color changes, speed and award selection work fine, I have 2 sound issues unfortunately. The first problem is that the sound does not match the color change of the roulette wheel, it seems that the sound is slower, the second problem is that the sound seems to go into an infinite loop since it never finishes playing

I realize that the first problem happens because the duration of the sound is greater than the duration of timeDelay (), when timeDelay > duration of sound, it matches the change of the selected rectangle with sound, but I need timeDelay () to be shorter for a fluid motion.

**Alternative 2**

When I substitute `mp.start();` for `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pin).start();` everything matches perfectly regardless of the duration of timeDelay (), but only the first 5 positions of the wheel, then the following loop occurs: silence of about 4 seconds, the sound is played 5 times and it never ends.

Hope someone can help me, thanks

Comment: Does this question help:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627101/playing-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time-in-android

Comment: It is the solution, thank you very much